# Azure AD deleted associated vnet

Tags: azure, active-directory, vnet

I have accidently deleted the virtual network that was associated with my Azure AD instance. Therefore I can´t join computers to that domain.

Is there a way to associate the Azure AD directory to another vnet?

If this is not possible, can I delete the Azure AD default directory and re-enable it choosing a new vnet without loosing my Azure Tenant?

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: pretty weird. it didnt let me delete that network saying it was in use. but tenant isnt something you can delete, i believe so if you recreate you will have the same tenant

Comment: ok, thanks. I will try to delete and recreate it.